# Nginx do strange 301 redirect

Tags: nginx

I have fresh installation of Nginx. It should just serve static files like pdf and images. But then I trying open the site by domain name in the first response I get 301 redirect and it point on real ip address. I dont have any redirects in my config but it doing it.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  .subdomain.example.com;
    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
       root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
       index  index.html index.htm;
   }
}
```

Comment: What OS? What version of Nginx? Are there any other vhost entries? Please provide as many info as possible to help you. Also, try enabling the debug log. http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html .

Comment: @Pothi Centos 7, Nginx 1.10

Comment: Are you sure your configuration is loaded (use `nginx -t` to check configuration, check error logs on reload signal, use `nginx -T` to see complete currently loaded configuration) ? Are you sure your client is connecting to the right endpoint? Are you sure you are being served by the right virtual host in nginx? Are you sure there is no cache (ie client-side) involved?